# unable to invoke the function within a loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am a student currently learning python and i wanted to take only numeric inputs from input() function and sort of check whether the inputs is all numeric. This is my code:

```
print('Input any random numbers here')
input1 = input('Input 1\n')
input2 = input('Input 2\n')
input3 = input('Input 3\n')
input4 = input('Input 4\n')
new_list = [input1, input2, input3, input4]
for data in new_list:
    if not data.isnumeric() == True:
        if not new_list[0].isnumeric() == True:
            del new_list[0]
            print('Rekey 1')
            input1 = input()
            new_list.insert(0, input1)
        elif not new_list[1].isnumeric() == True:
            del new_list[1]
            print('Rekey 2')
            input2 = input()
            new_list.insert(1, input2)
        elif not new_list[2].isnumeric() == True:
            del new_list[2]
            print('Rekey 3')
            input3 = input()
            new_list.insert(2, input3)
        elif not new_list[3].isnumeric() == True:
            del new_list[3]
            print('Rekey 4')
            input4 = input()
            new_list.insert(3, input4)
            print(new_list)
    else:
        print('Done Checking')
        print(new_list)
        break
```

To check I would create a list containing the variables: input 1, 2, 3, 4:`new_list = [input1, input2, input3, input4]`and implement a for loop to parse the variables within the list

But i realize that if i were to run this code by keying in alphabets (wrong value type) for the first input: input1. it will invoke the for loop to execute the code within it to check the inputs:

```
for data in new_list:
if not data.isnumeric() == True:
    if not new_list[0].isnumeric() == True:
        del new_list[0]
        print('Rekey 1')
        input1 = input()
        new_list.insert(0, input1)
    elif not new_list[1].isnumeric() == True:
        del new_list[1]
        print('Rekey 2')
        input2 = input()
        new_list.insert(1, input2)
    elif not new_list[2].isnumeric() == True:
        del new_list[2]
        print('Rekey 3')
        input3 = input()
        new_list.insert(2, input3)
    elif not new_list[3].isnumeric() == True:
        del new_list[3]
        print('Rekey 4')
        input4 = input()
        new_list.insert(3, input4)
        print(new_list)
else:
    print('Done Checking')
    print(new_list)
    break
```

However if i keyed in exactly the numerical value (correct value type) for input1 and  alphabetical value (wrong value type) for the rest of inputs variable: input2, input3 and input4 it somehow doesn't invoke the for loop to execute the code within it and check the inputs as mentioned above.'

I had reviewed my code a few times but i couldn't find the problem within it, all i could understand was that the iterables was exhausted but i didn't know how to solve it.

I hope someone could answer my doubts with something simple and no complicating functions needing of import

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Python! A few notes with this code:

1. "Hard coding" is usually a bad idea and you should avoid it
2. In python, there's no need to use del in most cases since python has an integrated memory manager
3. 'if not data.isnumeric() == True' could be rewritten as 'if not data.isnumeric()'
4. Your code doesn't work because if it encounters any value that is numeric, the loop breaks and the code ends.

All in all, I would rewrite your code like this:

```py
print('Input any random numbers here')
input1 = input('Input 1\n')
input2 = input('Input 2\n')
input3 = input('Input 3\n')
input4 = input('Input 4\n')
new_list = [input1, input2, input3, input4]

i = 0
while i < len(new_list):
    if not new_list[i].isnumeric():
        new_list[i] = input(f'Rekey {i+1}\n')
        i -= 1
    i += 1
```

Although this is probably not the most optimal solution, there's some things in there that you can try learning from. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: thanks for your answer and i would certainly try it out but may i ask what is hard coding?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help! i gave the code a try and it works! it solved my problem! but i still have doubt on what is hard coding and can u explain what is mean by iterable being exhausted and the ways to solve it?

Comment: @MelvinChing So hard coding is embedding data directly into the source code of a program as opposed to generating it at run-time. This is just a complicated way of saying try not to code in numbers/strings if you can avoid it. Instead, these numbers should __generally__ be generated through loops, calculations, etc. Of course, it's not always avoidable and there's also some personal reference about it as well. Since I can't really use this as a teaching platform, I will leave it at the fact that you should try to experiment with loops on your own; the best way I learned was through experience!